# Using PHP to update/edit MySQL tables: result-sets stored as JSON objects. Do I still need prepared statements?

Tags: mysql, security, mysqli, pdo, prepared-statement

I mean for security. Does converting to/from JSON objects help any with MySQLi?

My intention is to use MySQLi statements and send/receive everything as JSON objects (in order to in the future allow Android to use the same calls and queries.)

My only focus on this question is the security side of it. Do I need prepared statements if I'm converting everything to and from JSON objects for a MySQL database.

Comment: Probably not, but why wouldn't you use them anyway.

Comment: What Strawberry wrote - you probably don't need it but why would you avoid it? If you have queries that you repeat often, then you can *only benefit* from prepared statements so there's no reason to just use them in specific cases - every time you pass some sort of parameter to a query, use prepared statements.

Comment: Not really avoiding it per se. I have the JSON working correctly now and it's using MySQLi. I just wonder...because all  my other DB queries are using PDO with its named parameters `:person_id` and `:person_first_name` etc. Just wonder if I should try to force PDO on top of them as I'm relatively new working with JSON objects. (EDIT: The JSON objects are more of a test-phase on the website right now more than anything.) Thanks for the input though!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what kind of data you are storing in the database. To prevent against SQL injection you need to **parameterize all variable input in your SQL**. It makes no difference where this data comes from. It doesn't matter what it is.

There is no reason not to use prepared statements. Seriously, not a single reason why you should not use prepared statements 100% of the time, even for constant queries.

Remember though, that prepared statements do not protect against SQL injection. Only the parameters help. Use placeholders in your SQL and bind the data separately. Do this always.